# react sort list of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update make that when the button is clicked then the function `sortCategories` is executed and  the list of `CategoryRow` components is sorted  but nothing change and there are  no errors on the console

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './category.css';
import Header from "../Header";
import CategoryRow from "./CategoryRow";


// Clean empty categories
const filtered = window.CATEGORIES.filter(function(value, index, arr) {
    return value.labResults.length > 0;
});



export default function Category() {

    const [categories, setCategories] = useState(filtered)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(false)
    }, []);

    const sortCategories = () => {
        // Order by issues
        categories.sort((a,b) => {
            return b.issues - a.issues;
        });
        setCategories(categories);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Header></Header>
            <div className="order-button-row">
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={ sortCategories }>Order by issues</button>
            </div>
            <div className="card shadow py-2 mb-2">
                <div className="card-body">
                    {loading ? (
                        <div className={'text-center'}>
                            <span className="fa fa-spin fa-spinner fa-4x"></span>
                        </div>

                    ) : (
                        <div className={'row'}>
                            {categories.map(categoryInformation =>
                                <CategoryRow key={categoryInformation.category.id}
                                             category={categoryInformation.category}
                                             issues={categoryInformation.issues}></CategoryRow>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

In your code `categories.sort` does in-place sorting and when you do  `setCategories(categories)`, React simply ignores it since it is the same array reference as before (no reference change).

```
categories.sort((a,b) => {
  return b.issues - a.issues;
});
setCategories(categories);
```

#### Solution 1

Make a copy of the categories and then sort and update the state:

```
const categoriesCopy = [...categories];
categoriesCopy.sort((a,b) => {
    return b.issues - a.issues;
});
setCategories(categoriesCopy);
```

#### Solution 2

Use callback function of setter function:

```
setCategories(prevCategories => {
  const categoriesCopy = [...prevCategories];
  categoriesCopy.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.issues - a.issues;
  });
  return categoriesCopy;
});
```